# C++ Song printing issue

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am practising my programming skills by devising a program that prints "The Twelve Days of Christmas" song but the user inputs a number from 1-12 helping to determine the number of versus printed. I am close with my code but its not quite how I want. Currently the code looks like this:

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int day;
    cout << "How many days ( 1 to 12)?\n";
    cin >> day;
    if (day == 0) {

        return 0;
    }
    else if (day > 0) {   

    cout << "On the ";
        if (day == 2) {
        cout<< "2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me\n";    
        }

        else if (day == 3) {
            cout << "3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me\n"; 
        }
        else {
            cout << day << "th day of Christmas my true love gave to me\n"; 

        }
    switch (day) {
    case 12: cout << "Twelve Drummers Drumming\n";
    case 11: cout << "Eleven Pipers Piping\n";
    case 10: cout << "Ten Lords a-Leaping\n";
    case 9: cout << "Nine Ladies Dancing\n";
    case 8: cout << "Eight Maids a-Milking\n";
    case 7: cout << "Seven Swans a-Swimming\n";
    case 6: cout << "Six Geese a-Laying\n";
    case 5: cout << "Five Gold Rings\n";
    case 4: cout << "Four Calling Birds\n";
    case 3: cout << "Three French Hens\n";
    case 2: cout << "Two Turtle Doves, and\n";
    case 1: cout << "A Partridge in a Pear Tree\n\n";
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the user inputs a number e.g 4, and the output is:

```
How many days ( 1 to 12)?
4
On the 4th day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Four Calling Birds
Three French Hens
Two Turtle Doves, and
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
```

So it is on it's way however it is not how I need it to be, the desired output is:

```
How many days (1 to 12)? 
4
On the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me
A partridge in a pear tree.

On the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree.

On the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Three French hens,
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree.

On the 4th day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Four calling birds,
Three French hens,
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree.
```

I think I need to introduce another switch for the days but not actually sure.

Comment: you need a loop after the console input.Everything else should be in that loop

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over the sequence, cf. the snippet below:

```
for (int i=1; i <= day; i++) {
    switch (i) {
        case 12: cout << "Twelve Drummers Drumming\n";
        case 11: cout << "Eleven Pipers Piping\n";
        case 10: cout << "Ten Lords a-Leaping\n";
        case 9: cout << "Nine Ladies Dancing\n";
        case 8: cout << "Eight Maids a-Milking\n";
        case 7: cout << "Seven Swans a-Swimming\n";
        case 6: cout << "Six Geese a-Laying\n";
        case 5: cout << "Five Gold Rings\n";
        case 4: cout << "Four Calling Birds\n";
        case 3: cout << "Three French Hens\n";
        case 2: cout << "Two Turtle Doves, and\n";
        case 1: cout << "A Partridge in a Pear Tree\n\n";
    }
}
```

I originally had the order backwards, but now I recall that the songs start with `A Partridge in a Pear Tree` and works upwards from there.

**Note:** The loop will only execute for day numbers which are 1 or higher.  But you might also want to include a check to handle the case where the user enters a number higher than 12.

Comment: I think that won't print output lines like `On the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me` and similarly for 3 and 4. They should also be in loop

Comment: @RamandeepPunia how would you recommend I do the On the nth day of Christmas my true love gave to me part of the print

Comment: @Summ0102 The loop I gave should handle _any_ value.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your code does work thanks, question is I'm wondering how I can get it to print " On the x day of Christma........ etc " at the start of each verse, it also starts at the chosen verse and gets smaller, any ideas how I can reverse the way it prints out if that makes sense, so it prints 1 line, then two lines, then three etc

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen :  No, your code might not work properly. There will only be one `On the... ` output line. But there should be 3 more similar lines.

Comment: @Summ0102 As I recall the song, the preface `On the ...` is only recited _once_, at the start of a collection for a given day.

Comment: @Summ0102 Just put everything after `cin>>day` inside the same loop as Tim suggested

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string present[] = { "A Partridge in a Pear Tree",
                         "Two Turtle Doves, and",
                         "Three French Hens",
                         "Four Calling Birds",
                         "Five Gold Rings",
                         "Six Geese a-Laying",
                         "Seven Swans a-Swimming",
                         "Eight Maids a-Milking",
                         "Nine Ladies Dancing",
                         "Ten Lords a-Leaping",
                         "Eleven Pipers Piping",
                         "Twelve Drummers Drumming"
                        };

    int day;
    cout << "How many days ( 1 to 12)?\n";
    cin >> day;
    if (day == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (day > 0) {   

        for(int n = 1; n <= day; n++)
        {
            cout << "On the " << n;
            switch(n)
            {
                 case 1: cout << "st "; break;
                 case 2: cout << "nd "; break;
                 case 3: cout << "rd "; break;
                 default: cout << "th "; break;
            }
            cout << "day of Christmas my true love gave to me" << endl;

            for(int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                cout << present[i] << endl;
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is what I started with however it just prints the verse in which the user selected, my goal is to print all of the verses up to the one they input, so if you enter 4 at the beginning of the program it will print out 4 verses, like the example in my question.

Comment: It prints what you need. Try it.

Comment: it doesn't work  sorry,  it prints: 
How many days ( 1 to 12)?
4
On the 4th day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Four Calling Birds
Three French Hens
Two Turtle Doves, and
A Partridge in a Pear Tree
it should print How many days (1 to 12)? 
4
On the 1st day of Christmas my true love gave to me
A partridge in a pear tree.

On the 2nd day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree.

On the 3rd day of Christmas my true love gave to me
Three French hens,
Two turtle doves, and
A partridge in a pear tree.
etc

Comment: legend! I didn't know you could do it that way.

Comment: there is only one issue, its with the switch for the day, whenever it prints out the first line of each verse all the days have the same end, e.g. 3rd, 4rd, 5rd etc, any ideas how to fix